# Samba share file write/close, rename => permission denied

Tags: samba

Samba 3.6.3 on ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

clients windows server 2008 R2, 2012

From windows, On a samba share I am doing
- open dir1/file
- write dir1/file
- close dir1/file
- rename dir1/file dir2/file-new
- delete dir1/file

I am doing rename so the file can get atomically created in dir2/ dir.

Most of the time it works, but occasionally I get "permission denied" from rename followed by "file in use" from delete.

I see no errors in the smb.* logs.

smb.conf has oplocks = false

Is there anything in the SMB protocol, that would make such infrequent of this error possible ?